# Customizing My Account Orders list post per page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-accounts, orders

Woocommerce 2.6.x has a special page at the user account (My Account) area where it displays the user's previous Orders.

This page is now paginated and it displays as default 15 items/page.

Here the screenshot of the woocommerce storefront theme Orders area with 8 lines:
[image]

I Can't find the way to change this.

How can I show only 7 items instead of the default number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Using a custom hooked function in **`woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query`** hook, you can alter the orders query customizing the **`post_per_page`** argument to **7**, just as you want.

Here is that code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_my_account_orders', 10, 1 );
function custom_my_account_orders( $args ) {

    $args['posts_per_page'] = 7;
    return $args;
}
```

For woocommerce 3+ use `limit` instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_my_account_orders', 10, 1 );
function custom_my_account_orders( $args ) {
    // Set the post per page
    $args['limit'] = 7;

    return $args;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

> **Note:** Normally the default value for storefront theme and other themes too when displaying the list of orders in my account pages is **10** *(but not 15)*.

Comment: It worked yeah :) Thank you very much for your help. BTW I've pointed 15 since it's the number pointed at the WC page on the My Account 2.6.0! I might read it wrongly!

Comment: I am trying to customise ordering by shipping person name. Can you help me