# Remove pagination on My account orders list to make it one page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, pagination, orders

In woocommerce I would like to remove pagination on My account orders (list) to make it one page.

Is there a way to do it?

This page breaks my custom tabbed pages when it has more than 1 page. I would like to just make it as long list without pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code acts on the order query and change the number of orders per page to an unlimited value. That removes the pagination allowing to display all orders in one unique page:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_my_account_orders_query', 20, 1 );
function custom_my_account_orders_query( $args ) {
    $args['limit'] = -1;

    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Related: [Customizing My Account Orders list post per page in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916732/customizing-my-account-orders-list-post-per-page-in-woocommerce/41917875#41917875)

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick. I actually just rewrote the page entirely as I wanted other metrics from orders to be displayed... figured it easier than a 'patch' ... You are a legend in this forum @LoicTheAztec